# Check which fields in form are submitted and output in view

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a form with multiple inputs, and one submit button. A user doesn't have to fill in every field. The values inputed in the form are submitted to a database, and I can successfully output all of the values. The problem is I need to change the view dependant on which inputs have been submitted. 
E.g If a user submits a youtube link only, then only the YouTube I-frame is outputted.

My Form in a view:

```
  <?= $this->Form->create($work, ['class'=> 'worksform', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) ?>

<?= $this->Html->image('upload.png', ['class' => 'uploadform center']); ?>

<div class="worksformname"><?= $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.first_name')?> <?= $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.last_name');?></div>

<fieldset>
        <div class= "worksformtitle"><?= $this->Form->control('Title');?></div>

        <div class= "worksformcourse"><?= $this->Form->control('course_id', ['options' => $courses]);?></div>

        <div class= "worksformunit"><?= $this->Form->control('unit_id', ['options' => $units]); ?></div>

        <div class= "worksformdesc"><?= $this->Form->control('description');?></div>

        <p class="worksformtext">I want to upload a... </p>

        <li class="buttonworks">
        <button type="button" class="videoworks"id="videob"> Video Project </button>
        <button type="button" class="audioworks" id="audiob">  Audio Project</button>
        <button type="button" class="pdfworks" id="pdfb"> PDF File </button>
        <button type="button" class="imageworks" id="imageb"> Image File </button> </li>

        <div class="worksformvideo d-none" id="videof"><?= $this->Form->control('video_url')?> </div>

        <div class="worksformvideo d-none" id="audiof"><?= $this->Form->control('sound_url');?> </div>

        <div class="worksformvideo d-none"id="pdff"><?= $this->Form->control('pdf', ['type'=> 'file'])?> </div>

        <div class="worksformvideo d-none"id="imagef"><?= $this->Form->control('image', ['type'=> 'file'])?> </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="buttonbox">
  <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
</div>
    <?= $this->Form->end()?>
```

My Contoller:

```
 public function add()
{
    $work = $this->Works->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $work = $this->Works->patchEntity($work, $this->request->getData());
        $work->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        $file =$this->request->data['image'];
        $name =$this->request->data['image']['name'];
        $work->image_url = $name;

        $file =$this->request->data['pdf'];
        $name =$this->request->data['pdf']['name'];
        $work->pdf_url = $name;

        if ($this->Works->save($work)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'files/' . $name);
            $this->Flash->success(__('The work has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The work could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $users = $this->Works->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $units = $this->Works->Units->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $courses = $this->Works->Courses->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('work', 'users', 'units', 'courses'));


}
```

Output View:

```
    <div class="worksviewcontainer">
     <p class="worksunitcourseview"> <?= $work->course->name?> / <?= 
     $work->unit->name?></p>
     <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/<?= h($work->sound_url)?>&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"></iframe>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= h($work->video_url)?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<object data="<?= '/~i7437085/project/files/'.$work->pdf_url ?>" type="application/pdf" width="600" height="500">
    <embed src="<?= '/~i7437085/project/files/'.$work->pdf_url ?>" width="600px" height="500px" />
        <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: 
        <a href="<?= '/~i7437085/project/files/'.$work->pdf_url ?>">Download PDF</a>.</p> 
    </embed>
    </object>
<img class="pc" src="<?= '/~i7437085/project/files/'.$work->image_url ?>">
<p class="workstitleview"> <?= h($work->Title)?> </p>  
<p class="worksnameview"> Published by <?= $work->user->first_name?> <?=$work->user->last_name?> (<?= $work->course->name?>) on <?= h($work->created) ?></p>  
<p class="descheading">Description</p>             
<p class="worksdescview"><?= h($work->description); ?></p>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your validation allows empty inputs on add, that means that related fields in db should be "empty". That means, you can show your data in view depending on value of field:

```
<?php if(!empty($work->video_url)): ?>
    <iframe ... ></iframe>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can repeat that for all markup relevant to fields that can be empty.